# How can I save custom icons for shortcuts

Tags: windows, icons, shortcut

I have a shortcut with a custom icon on it, the icon shows fine until I try copy the shortcut to another machine.
I have the icon saved in the same folder as the shortcut yet it still does not show when copied to another machine.

I was wondering if there was a way to have this icon stored inside the shortcut or some way to have it get the icon from the current folder with a relative path?

Answer (score 0):

Icons cannot be stored inside a .lnk file and [you cannot use a relative path to the icon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14698777/3501).

The only thing you can use are environment variables (the .lnk will have a `EXP_SZ_ICON_SIG` data block).